# How to get internal Database/Table content in TYPO3 and display via JavaScript, JQuery or AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typo3, typo3-8.x

I am a beginner in TYPO3 and have to say its very complex but I am struggling my way through.

I just want a simple way to get content from an internal TYPO3 Database Table which I created and forward it to JavaScript/JQuery/AJAX.

My BootstrapTable is working but just displays static content from `var data`.

I know there are ways from pageType, eID and `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows( /* ... */ );` to get the content of the Database Table, but how to forward it to JavaScript and display it?

There should not be another database call with credentials, just a way to the internal Database.

Searching for this answer since 2 days but can't find any easy and plausible answer.
Or do I have to take the long road via eID or pageType?

Edit due to comment:

Here is my JavaScript with bootstrapTable:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        idField: 'name',
        pagination: true,
        search: true,
        data: data,
        columns: [{
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Name'
        }, {
            field: 'stargazers_count',
            title: 'Stars'
        }, {
            field: 'forks_count',
            title: 'Forks'
        }, {
            field: 'description',
            title: 'Description'
        }],
        onPostBody: function () {
            $('#table').editableTableWidget({editor: $('<textarea>')});
        }
    });
});

var data = [{
        "name": "bootstrap-table",
        "stargazers_count": "526",
        "forks_count": "122",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) "
    }, {
        "name": "multiple-select",
        "stargazers_count": "288",
        "forks_count": "150",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    }, {
        "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
        "stargazers_count": "32",
        "forks_count": "11",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    }, {
        "name": "blog",
        "stargazers_count": "13",
        "forks_count": "4",
        "description": "my blog"
    }, {
        "name": "scutech-redmine",
        "stargazers_count": "6",
        "forks_count": "3",
        "description": "Redmine notification tools for chrome extension."
    }
];
```

And calling it in my html with : `<table id="table"></table>`
My own created table in mysql database is: `tx_table`

I want the content of that table to be displayed in my bootstraptable Table

Comment: Need more info. There are 2 ways to get into frontend. Output into a script tag in html. Get it via ajax using a custom route. You can use [vhs:EncodeViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Format/Json/EncodeViewHelper.html) to make a json from php object.

Comment: Hello Andrew,
I edited my question, hopefully its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

First solution. You can output your results directly into html using `<script>` tag and `v:format.json.encode` ViewHelper

action code:

```
$yourDataArrayFromPHP = array(
    'var1' => 'val1',
    'var2' => 'val2'
);

$this->view->assign('yourDataArrayFromPHP', $yourDataArrayFromPHP);
```

html:

```
<script>
    var data = {v:format.json.encode(value: '{yourDataArrayFromPHP}')}
</script>
```

Now you can access this data in javascript `data.var1`
Also keep in mind that your data should be before bootstrapTable initialization.